# How to auto generate user input choice by found file extensions without manually editing script

Tags: batch-file, input, set

I want to recursively search a folder for all exe files and have the batch script automatically set each program.exe file found as a user choice input. It needs to auto-populate the choices appropriately and stop when the last exe is found. So if there are a total of 8 exe files in the searched folder then it would auto output set /p choice of 8 programs.exe's to choose from. Not 9 choices and not 7. The exact number of choices needs to be accurate for all found matches. This is an attempt to streamline the coding process.

I have a massive script I made that will auto populate up to 6 found exe files. There lies my problem. I am capped. The script works well for what it is but I am hoping someone has a trick up their sleve and a new way of thinking about the code execution. I won't lie when I say that this script I made is a bit of a mess. Thanks in advance to anyone who might have some ideas.

Important note: I downloaded and exe program called cecho.exe that helps colorize the terminal output text. I highly recommend using it if you want to debug my script. It would be a giant mess without it. Stick cecho.exe in your system32 folder or whever you want as long as it can be accessed with out needing the full path to the file. I found the program here (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17033/Add-Colors-to-Batch-Files)

```
@echo off
if not "%1" == "max" start /max cmd /i /c %0 max & exit/b
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set extension=exe
set nt={\n \t}
set ntt={\n \t \t}
set "TAB= "

:: CECHO RED ::
set cred=cecho {0C}
call :cred
exit /b
:cred
setlocal
echo !cred!
endlocal
:: CECHO GREEN ::
set cgreen=cecho {0A}
call :cgreen
exit /b
:cgreen
setlocal
echo !cgreen!
endlocal
:: CECHO YELLOW ::
set cyellow=cecho {0E}
call :cyellow
exit /b
:cyellow
setlocal
echo !cyellow!
endlocal
:: CHOICE ::
set choice=1
call :choice1
exit/b
:choice1
setlocal
echo !choice!
endlocal
goto start

:start
cls
cd "%~dp0"

call :choice1
exit/b
:choice1
setlocal
set choice=!choice!
endlocal
for /r "." %%i in (*.%extension%) do (
set p!choice!=%%~nxi
set /a choice=!choice!+1
)

echo.
call :cyellow
exit /b
:cyellow
setlocal
!cyellow! ...........................................................%ntt2%
!cyellow!     Select a number{\n}
!cyellow! ...........................................................{\n}{#}
endlocal
pause
echo.


set p1=!p1!
call :p1
exit /b
:p1
setlocal
if "%p1%"=="" goto nomatch
if defined p1 (
call :p1
)
:p1
call :cred
call :cgreen
:cred
:cgreen
setlocal
!cred!%ntt%1.
!cgreen! !p1!%ntt%
echo.

set p2=!p2!
call :p2
exit /b
:p2
setlocal
if "%p2%"=="" goto sel_1
if defined p2 (
call :p2
)
:p2
!cred!%ntt%2.
!cgreen! !p2!%ntt%
echo.

set p3=!p3!
call :p3
exit /b
:p3
setlocal
if "%p3%"=="" goto sel_2
if defined p3 (
call :p3
)
:p3
!cred!%ntt%3.
!cgreen! !p3!%ntt%
echo.

set p4=!p4!
call :p4
exit /b
:p4
setlocal
if "%p4%"=="" goto sel_3
if defined p4 (
call :p4
)
:p4
!cred!%ntt%4.
!cgreen! !p4!%ntt%
echo.

set p5=!p5!
call :p5
exit /b
:p5
setlocal
if "%p5%"=="" goto sel_4
if defined p5 (
call :p5
)
:p5
!cred!%ntt%5.
!cgreen! !p5!%ntt%
echo.

set p6=!p6!
call :p6
exit /b
:p6
setlocal
if "%p6%"=="" goto sel_5
if defined p6 (
call :p6
)
:p6
!cred!%ntt%6.
!cgreen! !p6!%ntt%
goto sel_6
echo.

:sel_1
echo.
echo The selected program is !p1!
set "input="
set /p "input=Select a number or type reset to go to beginning:"
if %input%==reset goto startover
if %input%==1 goto ex1

:sel_2
echo.
echo sel_2
set "input="
set /p "input=Select a number or type reset to go to beginning:"
if %input%==reset goto startover
if %input%==2 goto ex2
if %input%==1 goto ex1

:sel_3
echo.
echo sel_3
set "input="
set /p "input=Select a number or type reset to go to beginning:"
if %input%==reset goto startover
if %input%==3 goto ex3
if %input%==2 goto ex2
if %input%==1 goto ex1

:sel_4
echo.
echo sel_4
set "input="
set /p "input=Select a number or type reset to go to beginning:"
if %input%==reset goto startover
if %input%==4 goto ex4
if %input%==3 goto ex3
if %input%==2 goto ex2
if %input%==1 goto ex1

:sel_5
echo.
echo sel_5
set "input="
set /p "input=Select a number or type reset to go to beginning:"
if %input%==reset goto startover
if %input%==5 goto ex5 
if %input%==4 goto ex4
if %input%==3 goto ex3
if %input%==2 goto ex2
if %input%==1 goto ex1

:sel_6
echo.
set "input="
set /p "input=Select a number or type reset to go to beginning:"
if %input%==reset goto startover
if %input%==6 goto ex6
if %input%==5 goto ex5
if %input%==4 goto ex4
if %input%==3 goto ex3
if %input%==2 goto ex2
if %input%==1 goto ex1

:ex1
cls
!cyellow! ...............................................{\n}
!cgreen!%ntt% You have chosen{\n}
!cred!%ntt%   !p1!{\n}
!cyellow! ...............................................{\n}
timeout 1 >nul
echo.
!cyellow! & set "input=Select [1] to Install or Select [2] to Uninstall:"
set /p "input=!input!"
if %input%==2 goto un1
if %input%==1 goto in1

:ex2
cls
!cyellow! ...............................................{\n}
!cgreen!%ntt% You have chosen{\n}
!cred!%ntt%   !p2!{\n}
!cyellow! ...............................................{\n}
timeout 1 >nul
echo.
!cyellow! & set "input=Select [1] to Install or Select [2] to Uninstall:"
set /p "input=!input!"
if %input%==2 goto un2
if %input%==1 goto in2

:ex3
cls
!cyellow! ...............................................{\n}
!cgreen!%ntt% You have chosen{\n}
!cred!%ntt%   !p3!{\n}
!cyellow! ...............................................{\n}
timeout 1 >nul
echo.
!cyellow! & set "input=Select [1] to Install or Select [2] to Uninstall:"
set /p "input=!input!"
if %input%==2 goto un3
if %input%==1 goto in3

:ex4
cls
!cyellow! ...............................................{\n}
!cgreen!%ntt% You have chosen{\n}
!cred!%ntt%   !p4!{\n}
!cyellow! ...............................................{\n}
timeout 1 >nul
echo.
!cyellow! & set "input=Select [1] to Install or Select [2] to Uninstall:"
set /p "input=!input!"
if %input%==2 goto un4
if %input%==1 goto in4

:ex5
cls
!cyellow! ...............................................{\n}
!cgreen!%ntt% You have chosen{\n}
!cred!%ntt%   !p5!{\n}
!cyellow! ...............................................{\n}
timeout 1 >nul
echo.
!cyellow! & set "input=Select [1] to Install or Select [2] to Uninstall:"
set /p "input=!input!"
if %input%==2 goto un5
if %input%==1 goto in5

:ex6
cls
!cyellow! ...............................................{\n}
!cgreen!%ntt% You have chosen{\n}
!cred!%ntt%   !p6!{\n}
!cyellow! ...............................................{\n}
timeout 1 >nul
echo.
!cyellow! & set "input=Select [1] to Install or Select [2] to Uninstall:"
set /p "input=!input!"
if %input%==2 goto un6
if %input%==1 goto in6

:in1
cls
set p1=!p1!
call :p1
exit /b
:p1
setlocal
timeout 1 >nul
echo.
echo You are about to Install !p1!
pause
set /p verify=Are you sure you want to Install !p1! (y/[n])?
if /i "%verify%" neq "y" goto startover
start "" !p1!
goto end

:in2
cls
echo You are about to Install !p2!
timeout 1 >nul
echo.
set /p verify=Are you sure you want to Install !p2! (y/[n])?
if /i "%verify%" neq "y" goto startover
start "" !p2!
goto end

:in3
cls
echo You are about to Install !p3!
timeout 1 >nul
echo.
set /p verify=Are you sure you want to Install !p3! (y/[n])?
if /i "%verify%" neq "y" goto startover
start "" !p3!
goto end

:in4
cls
echo You are about to Install !p4!
timeout 1 >nul
echo.
set /p verify=Are you sure you want to Install !p4! (y/[n])?
if /i "%verify%" neq "y" goto startover
start "" !p4!
goto end

:in5
cls
echo You are about to Install !p5!
timeout 1 >nul
echo.
set /p verify=Are you sure you want to Install !p5! (y/[n])?
if /i "%verify%" neq "y" goto startover
start "" !p5!
goto end

:in6
cls
echo You are about to Install !p6!
timeout 1 >nul
echo.
set /p verify=Are you sure you want to Install !p6! (y/[n])?
if /i "%verify%" neq "y" goto startover
start "" !p6!
goto end

:un1
cls
echo You are about to Uninstall !p1!
timeout 1 >nul
echo.
set /p verify=Are you sure you want to Uninstall !p1! (y/[n])?
if /i "%verify%" neq "y" goto startover
start "" !p1!
goto end

:un2
cls
echo You are about to Uninstall !p2!
timeout 1 >nul
echo.
set /p verify=Are you sure you want to Uninstall !p2! (y/[n])?
if /i "%verify%" neq "y" goto startover
start "" !p2!
goto end

:un3
cls
echo You are about to Uninstall !p3!
timeout 1 >nul
echo.
set /p verify=Are you sure you want to Uninstall !p3! (y/[n])?
if /i "%verify%" neq "y" goto startover
start "" !p3!
goto end

:un4
cls
echo You are about to Uninstall !p4!
timeout 1 >nul
echo.
set /p verify=Are you sure you want to Uninstall !p4! (y/[n])?
if /i "%verify%" neq "y" goto startover
start "" !p4!
goto end

:un5
cls
echo You are about to Uninstall !p5!
timeout 1 >nul
echo.
set /p verify=Are you sure you want to Uninstall !p5! (y/[n])?
if /i "%verify%" neq "y" goto startover
start "" !p5!
goto end

:un6
cls
echo You are about to Uninstall !p6!
timeout 1 >nul
echo.
set /p verify=Are you sure you want to Uninstall !p6! (y/[n])?
if /i "%verify%" neq "y" goto startover
start "" !p6!
goto end

:startover
cls
%cgreen% Restarting script from beginning{\n}
timeout 1 >nul
echo.
%cgreen% Try another option{\n}
timeout 1 >nul
goto start

:nomatch
cls
echo.
%cyellow% ...................................................................................................%ntt%
%cyellow%              The script found no matching extensions{\n}
%cyellow% ...................................................................................................{\n}
timeout 2 >nul
echo.
%cyellow% ...................................................................................................%ntt%
%cyellow%     Make sure to run script in folder with matching extensions{\n}
%cyellow% ...................................................................................................{\n}
timeout 2 >nul
echo.
%cyellow% ...................................................................................................%ntt%
%cyellow%                  Press any key to exit script{\n}
%cyellow% ...................................................................................................{\n}
timeout /t -1 >nul
goto end

:end
endlocal
exit
```

Comment: I'll take out the bulk of the script that I posted and leave the part that centers around my more specific question. Maybe that will be a better idea. Thanks.

Comment: I rolled back your edit due to some important parts being removed, anyway, we can cleanup some comments here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is a little more automated method, seeing as you are doing pretty much the same with each executable.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set cnt=0
for /r %%i in (*.exe) do (
    set /a cnt+=1
    set "file!cnt!=%%~fi"
    call echo [!cnt!] %%file!cnt!%%
)
set /p "ans=::: Please Select Executable from above list by matching number :::: "
choice /C IUC /M "Do you want to [I]nstall, [U]ninstall '!file%ans%!' or [C]ancel'"
if errorlevel 3 goto :eof
if errorlevel 2 (
    choice /C YN /M "Are you sure you want to Uninstall '!file%ans%!'"
    if errorlevel 2 goto :eof
    if errorlevel 1 echo start "" "!file%ans%!" Uninstall procedure here
    goto :eof
)
if errorlevel 1 (
    choice /C YN /M "Are you sure you want to Install '!file%ans%!'"
    if errorlevel 2 goto :eof
    if errorlevel 1 echo start "" "!file%ans%!" Install procedure here
    goto :eof
)
```

It will simply list each executable, you select the number corresponding to it, it will ask for install/uninstall and verify once, then in this case it will echo the install/uninstall procedure. You would simply need to modify it to add your actual procedures.. I am showing you the idea, you have to expand it to suit your needs `:)`

Comment: Hey I have not had a chance to sit down and take a look. Just wanted to say thank you for your help. As soon as I get a chance to test I will let you know how it went. Thanks again for everything.

Comment: I’ve only had a few moments to test but it works GREAT. Thank you! I’ll tweak it to my needs now that I have the core concept! Thanks a ton Gerhard!